# Adding a subdomain in cPanel with minimal DNS entries

Tags: cpanel, subdomain

When I create a Subdomain via cPanel on my hosted server all is good, but it creates many DNS entries besides subdomain.example.com and www.subdomain.example.com -- Like:

```
cpcalendars.subdomain.example.com
cpanel.subdomain.example.com
cpcontacts.subdomain.example.com
whm.subdomain.example.com
webdisk.subdomain.example.com
webmail.subdomain.example.com
```

My application has no need for these entries.  I have many subdomains and am adding some each day.  I would rather not have to delete the extra 6 DNS entries each time.

Is there a way to tell cPanel not to create these DNS entries?
A cPanel tweak setting (didn't see one), a file that defines the prefixes of DNS entries to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the default DNS templates within WHM . Refer to the documentation below.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1144Docs/Edit+Zone+Templates

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why 24x7cloudservermanagement said that, because he's completely wrong, and editing the zone templates won't help at all.

You can disable that feature by turning off the following:

WHM -> Server Configuration-> Tweak Settings -> Service subdomain creation